# Datepicker in three different textboxes

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to apply datepicker in my project. It's easy to apply it on a single textbox. But I want I will apply three to pick full date means I'm using three textboxes one for day, second for month and last for year.

Now what do I want? I want when I click in  day's textbox only dates will pop up. When I click in month's textbox month's pop up comes out and the same for year's textbox.

Comment: Datepicker only works for picking dates. It does not split into DayPicker, MonthPicker, and YearPicker.

Comment: Then why do you use Datepicker? Why not just making three dropdownboxes? Style them with css and you'll have exactly what you want.

Comment: i know sir but sir its users requirement he want this....

Comment: You need to seriously re-think your UI design. What you are attempting does not conform to accepted UI standards. If your user is requiring this, ask him/her to show you an example on the web that does this, then copy their code. If he/she can't find one, then you can use that as an example of why NOT to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, how about an alternative with this one: http://keith-wood.name/dateEntry.html by Keith Wood - spinners on each part...

FYI, I really like his time picker also :)

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery UI datepicker is simply not the tool for the job.  You might be able to use some of the techniques it uses.

If you're going to do a three-input date picker, you might want to consider having your inputs be `<select>` elements instead of just inputs.